# Implementing a controlled sum operation

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction

I want to implement a controlled operation that involves the following: we have the following qubits: $|x_0\rangle,|x_1\rangle,|0\rangle,|1\rangle,|z_0\rangle,|z_1\rangle$. I want to add the first four qubits as $|x_0x_1\rangle$ and $|01\rangle$ where each $x_i\in\{0,1\}$ conditioned on the  $|z_1\rangle$ being $0$. If the control is $1$ then do not perform the adder mod operation. So the circuit for this that I constructed is given in the figure:

[image: Controlled ADD MOD 4]

Is this circuit correct?

**Edit:** Just to elaborate what this circuit does. It  takes $3$ non-negative integer inputs $x=|x_0x_1\rangle$, $1=|01\rangle$, $z=|z_0z_1\rangle$ and adds the first two integers that are stored in the register $|x_0x_1\rangle$ and $|10\rangle$. The third integer $|z\rangle$ gives a remainder of $2$ when divided by $4$, but this can be thought of as the least significant bit being equal to $0$. Is the problem statement and circuit construction matching?

Comment: What does $z_0$ do?

Comment: $z_0$ is not required for this computation but it will he used for further operation. at this moment it does not play a part

Comment: @Upstart I'm curious what the larger project you are working on is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second from the top wire should probably be marked $|x_1 \rangle$ instead of $|x_0 \rangle$ (right now you have two $|x_0 \rangle$s). Other than that, the circuit looks correct for the described task.

Comment: yes that is $|x_1\rangle$